# XNA Game Studio 3.1 and Zune HD (How to render a 3D texture/model)

Tags: c#, zune-hd

I am wondering if anyone can find a sample or has a sample or knows how to draw a 3D Model on the Zune HD.

It appears Microsoft limited the functionality of XNA for the Zune HD by removing the Model object.  Is there a way they suggest replacing this object, or is there something else that can be done to draw Models?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there isn't really a way to do it at the moment, I know somebody has tried but it didn't work out very well.

The first link takes you to a discussion about why it's not available and the second takes you to the attempt at using 3d objects on the Zune.

[Lack of 3d - Zune](http://forums.xna.com/forums/t/42217.aspx)

[3d Attempt](http://www.catalinzima.com/?page_id=353)

It seems like it's something that might not be available for a while, if at all.

Comment: Unfortunate answer, but one that has potential, thanks alot.  Hopefully Microsoft cleans thier act up and makes more stuff available.

Comment: Happy to help, I wish they'd of improved support for the Zune instead of adding Avatar support for example.